# How to create a Blackberry notification message that opens the app like twitter does?

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

does anyone know what is the actual code to create a local notification in the Blackberry app that has a customized application icon and when the user clicks on the notification in the inbox, it goes directly to a specific page in the application? 
This is similar to how Twitter for blackberry works, whereby you can be notified of new tweets via your inbox and on clicking on the link brings you to the tweets list in the twitter app. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot or two of the Twitter functionality you're talking about?

Comment: here it is, notice the 13 and twitter logo on top...
http://www.getblackberry.info/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/b597a46599WFDej.jpg.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is referred to as Message List integration or sometimes as Message Folders.  Note that the name "message folder' is a little misleading. This isn't to create a "folder" that the user has to go into  (that threw me off first); rather it creates the message in the inbox as you describe.  For the best user experience you'll also want to create an [application notification icon](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/messagelist/ApplicationIcon.html).

The package name to concern yourself with is [net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/messagelist/package-tree.html). You will need to implement ApplicationMessage to do what you've requested.

There is an example of how to do this in the sample source code that ships with the JDE, the project name is "MessageListDemo".  All JDEs dating back to (at least) OS 4.5 will have it this sample app. If you want to use the new notification bar integration for OS6, make sure to take a look at the 6.0 MessageListDemo.

Here is a [quick overview of the process and bare-bones example](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/App-Integration-summary.html#AI_MessagesApp). It's for 6.0 but I believe the API they remains the same back to 4.6, and had minor changes from 4.5).  The MessageListDemo sample will be better though, as it's more thorough and includes everything you'll need to do -- such as implementing MessageFolderListener to detect when the user opens one of your custom messages.

Finally - I see that you have asked many questions but not accepted any answers, even valid ones. Please make sure to accept this answer if it helps you in order to ensure people keep replying to your questions.

Comment: Marc,thanks for the answers and thanks for caring enough to point out the fact that i forgot to click the accepted checkmark. I did vote up on the good answers,but along the way,i forgot about the checkmark. Your answer here is correct,along the way,i realize i need to implement this using webworks so i am still waiting for blackberry support on it. I'll also try to put checkmarks back on the past questions as well. Thanks again

Comment: np, thank you for going back and doing that.  I am just learning Webworks myself; my understanding is that RIM is actively developing the platform to add as much integration as possible -- so I wouldn't be surprised to see this coming soon.

Comment: Yes, you can find the message list feature under active development here...lets hope it will be released soon.
https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks/wiki/Enhancement-Candidates